# How to create index on expression in Liquibase XML

Tags: liquibase

I would like to create an index on an expression over a table field using the Liquibase XML syntax.
Can someone pls advise how this could be achieved?
An example of the equivalent SQL expression:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_idx
ON mytable USING btree
(
   "substring"((address), '(.*)-\d$')
);
```

Comment: how about using `<sql>` tag inside liquibase XML changeset?

Comment: Nope. I'm looking for an XML way of doing this.

Comment: May be try using `modifySql` tag with `createIndex` of liquibase.  With `modifySql` you can use `<append value=" USING btree ('substring'((address), '(.*)-\d$'));"/>`. Haven't tried it ever. Might work.